# Node JS res.sendFile() not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm getting `ReferenceError: main is not defined`
when I open up the http://localhost:3000/

Here I try to open up the main.html located in views directory

**This is my app.js**

```
const express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  config = require('./config/index'),
  routes = require('./routes/route');

app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/views`));
app.use('/',routes);
app.listen(config.port,()=>{
console.log(`Listing at port ${config.port}`)})
```

**This is my route.js**

```
const express = require('express'),
router = express.Router(),
helpers = require('../helpers/index');

router.route('/')
.get(helpers.index)

module.exports = router
```

**This is my helpers/index.js**

```
var user = require('../user/user');

exports.index = (req,res)=>{
    if(user.name == ''){
        res.sendFile(main.html);
    }
    else{    
        res.sendFile(chat.html)
    }
}

module.exports = exports;
```

**Directory Structure**

```
>helpers
  >index.js
>routes
  >route.js
>user
  >user.js
>views
  >main.html
  >chat.html
app.js
pacakage.json
```

Comment: edit: used res.render as a test to render ejs still that error?

Comment: `res.sendFile(main.html)` should give you syntax error because variable `main` does not exist. Hint: you are trying to access the property `html` of the variable `main`

Comment: what @slebetman is trying to say is to make `main.html` a string: `res.sendFile('main.html')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to jfriend00's answer, you must also, build the correct absolute path, using the global **__dirname** variable in node.

So your path will be something like: `res.sendFile(__dirname + "/main.html")`
or, depending on your folder structure: `res.sendFile(__dirname + "/someadditionalfoldrs/main.html")`

or, construct the path using "./" if applicable, like "./main.html";

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
res.sendFile(main.html);
```

to:

```
res.sendFile("main.html");
```

Without the quotes, it's trying to interpret `main` as a Javascript object which it looks for the `.html` property on.  But, there is apparently no object named `main` so you get `ReferenceError: main is not defined`.  You want to pass a string here instead.

Same for `res.sendFile("chat.html");`

---

If the files are not local to this module's directory, then you need to build a more complete path that specifies their location.  Given the file hierarchy you show, I think that might be something like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const options = {root: path.join(__dirname, "../views")};

res.sendFile("main.html", options);
```

Comment: In that case i get `TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile`

Comment: @PrashantBhardwaj - Then, you need to build a more complete path to the location of the files.  I've added an example to my answer that shows that.

Answer (score 3):

```
var user = require('../user/user');
var path = require('path');

exports.index = (req,res)=>{
    if(user.name == ''){
        res.sendFile(path.resolve('views/main.html'));
    }
    else{    
        res.sendFile(path.resolve('views/chat.html'))
    }
}

module.exports = exports;
```