# Invoking Angular from Node produces error

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am attempting to invoke Angular from node but am getting the following error in the browser. Angular is invoked successfully when "node server" is used.

Error:

```
runtime.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
polyfills.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
styles.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
scripts.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
vendor.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
main.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

server.js

```
const path = require('path');

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
process.env.INDEX = path.join(__dirname, '/dist/nghd01/index.html');

const configureMongoose = require('./backend/config/mongoose')
const configureExpress = require('./backend/config/express')

const app = configureExpress();

app.listen(4200);
```

express.js

```
module.exports = function() {
    const app = express();

    require('../app/routes/index.server.routes')(app);

    return app;
}
```

index.server.routes.js

```
const index = require('../controllers/index.server.controller');

module.exports = (app) => {
    app.get('/*', index.render);
};
```

index.server.controller.js

```
exports.render = (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(process.env.INDEX)
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do including angular on a server?

Comment: I am not including angular on the server, I am invoking angular from the server.

Comment: sorry, what's the difference? You need angular to get the access the angular environment

Comment: i'm not really sure what you want to do... but it seems that your are looking to implemente SSR (server side rendering). If so, you might want to [RTM](https://angular.io/guide/universal). If not, please give more details on what you are trying to do :)

Comment: I am trying to do exactly what is asked in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665797/node-js-res-sendfile-not-working

Comment: still very unclear on what you are trying to archive... are you trying to implement SSR or just serve your app?

Comment: I am trying ot serve the app.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a line in express.js. I did not specify the location of the static files like so:

```
app.use(express.static(process.env.DIST))
```